# Using Structs in other parts of code, form

Tags: c#, winforms, struct

I've got a class where I've declared this struct

```
public struct Tasks
{
    public string tName;
    public string tDate;
    public string tPriority;
    public string tDescription;
}
```

In `Form1`, I've constructed

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Tasks[] entry=new Tasks[taskName.Length];
    }
}
```

This works fine and dandy, but I want to use entry struct one a button press.

```
 private void TaskName1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form2 frm = new Form2(entry[i].tDate, entry[i].tName, entry[i].tPriority);
     frm.Show();  
 }
```

It obviously gives the warning "The name "entry" does no exist in the current context".

I'm fairly new to programming, but I have spent a few hours trying many things to no avail.

I've tried finding ways to make the `entry[array]` public somehow.
I've created public class and declared the struct and construct public, but still I couldn't get it to work.

I wanted to use the entry struct to send to another form because that's where I hold information and I will use the struct to write to ext files.

Any solutions or better ways to do this?

How can I use a struct across multiple forms, classes, etc.? Basically anywhere.

Comment: What class is Tasks inside? You have to reference it as ThatClass.Tasks if it's in another class.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you a) not to use mutable structs; b) not to use public fields; c) not to use a plural for a type name which actually represents a single value; d) not to use `t` as a prefix. It looks like this should be a class.

Comment: you init local variables in form constructor, so you can not get it in click handler

Comment: Tasks is in a separate class file
Class1.cs
`namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
       public struct Tasks
       {
          public string tName;
          public string tDate;
          public string tPriority;
          public string tDescription;
       }`
The struct works, I used to assign .Text on buttons and labels.

Comment: What is the purpose of this statement in your method: `Tasks entry=new Tasks();` ? What are you intending that to achieve?

Comment: That was an error in pasting code here, I will edit

Comment: it seems you declared "entry" in the Form1() constructor therefore only accessible in that constructor. you need to declare it outside (in a global area..i.e above "public Form1()") in order for it to be accessed by other methods within the same class in this context

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Thank you very much, that seemed to make it work for the button. DO you know where to declare it so it works across multiple forms?

Comment: you could maybe have a static class shared across the forms but you will face Multithreading issues if you are doing multithreading.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, you really should not use a `struct` in this manner - it violates several principles of basic object-oriented programming. You should generally declare it as a singular class (I.e. `public class Task`); as well as change your *fields* to *properties*; and remove the `t` from the name of each object. (You could replace it with an `m`; but generally they are usually `camelCase` with no prefix; in any case you should declare them as `private` and create `public` *properties* that implement them, or change them to *properties* in general.) Of course, all of these are up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You keep your Tasks array inside the constructor of your form. So it's visible only within the scope of the constructor. To make it visible for other Form1 members it has to be declared on the level of your Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Tasks[] entry;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        entry = new Tasks[taskName.Length];
    }
}
```

This is only to make your syntax correct. Whether your approach is worth pursuing is entirely different question and I strongly advise you to read through the comments to your question.

Comment: I would ideally like to share the entry[] across all forms, could you possible nudge me in the right direction. Thanks I just tried what you suggested and it works, I'll keep this in mind for other variables.

Comment: Consider if you really need to have an object exposed to all your forms. If you access data in the form it's either to display them to the user or to allow the user to modify them. Does your app benefits from allowing user to edit the same data on many different forms? Still, if you want to make some data available to other forms consider properties or events.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to reference a local variable declared in the constructor in a method that knows nothing about this variable.  C# has a concept called "scope", in which variable declarations are only accessible by the block of code that creates them.  ie. If you declare a variable inside method MyMethod(), you can only directly access it inside MyMethod().  Scopes can be nested, too, with any nested scope being able to access any variables in the parent scope, but not vice-versa.  For example:

```
class MyClass {
    int someInt = 0;

    void MyMethod() {
        int anotherInt = 5;
        someInt += 1;    // This works, as someInt was declared as a class-wide variable.
    }

    void AnotherMethod() {
        anotherInt = 6;    // Will not work!  anotherInt was declared in MyMethod, so is in a separate scope than that of AnotherMethod.

        string aString = "asd";


        if (someInt == 0) {    // Again, this works because this variable is declared in the parent scope.
            string anotherString = "fgh";
            aString = "asdasd";    // Works
        }

        anotherString = "oh no";    // Does not work, because if-statements create their own scope!
    }
}
```

Basically, every time you see an opening curly brace ( { ), you know that a new scope is being created.

Move the declaration outside of the Form1() constructor, and just define it in the constructor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Tasks[] entry;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        entry = new Tasks[taskName.Length];
    }
}
```

You can then reference entry from any methods inside Form1.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will link your comment to others I know who are starting out. Do you have an ideas about how to make the entry struct accessible across all forms?

Comment: There are 4 ways of doing that.  Make the entry variable public by simple adding "public" before "Tasks[]".  Then, you would need to pass a reference to your Form1 instance to any form you would like to access it from.  Use the "this" keyword to get the instance of the current class.  Alternatively, mark Tasks[] entry as public static.  You would then access it using Form1.entry.  Thirdly, move entry to a singleton class.  The fourth option is to pass entry to any forms that you want to be able to access it.

Comment: I've added   
`static public class Variables
       {
          Tasks[] entry =new Tasks[10];
       }`
But then every instance of entry on form1 "Does not exist in current context" even when i preface them with Variables.Entry[.....
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you mark anything as static, it means that only 1 instance of it will ever be created.  If you mark a class as static and want to access members or methods inside that class, you also need to mark them as static.  A better way of doing this would be to create a singleton class.  A singleton is a class that holds a static instance of itself.  Every time you want to access anything inside that class, you first get the instance.  Here's an example of a singleton: http://pastebin.com/F3mJtB01  And here's an example using all of the previous methods I spoke about: http://pastebin.com/74V064M5

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that this is an inappropriate use of `struct`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Just as a reminder, please don't forget to mark an answer to your question as such.  Thank you.